# A PostgreSQL 12 docker container failing to restart on a particular architecture

Tags: postgresql, docker

The problem is very simple and easily reproduced if you have a Raspberry Pi.  I am attempting to restore a postgresql 12 database running inside a docker container from a base backup, but the problem stopping this happening is simply that with PG 12 and armv71 I can't restart the container having deleted the data directory, as explained below.

I am using the official [postgresql docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) via DockerHub on two different environments, one is my local dev environment which is a PC running Ubuntu 18 LTS, the other is a Raspberry Pi armv71.

The operation that I require is to delete the content of `/var/lib/postgresql/data` on the running container, and then restart the container, this according to the documentation will force the docker-entrypoint.sh script to run, allowing my restore scripts to fire (which it does on my Ubuntu machine).

So on my PC this process works fine:

```
docker run --name website_db_1
```

This simply launches the default/vanilla postgresql docker container (I've left out the password on purpose)

Then, once up and running, to force the container to run the docker-entrypoint.sh script I do:

```
docker exec -it website_db_1 bash -c "rm /var/lib/postgresql/data/* -r"
docker container restart website_db_1
```

The container should re-initialise, and as I side point, if I were to add my appropriate restore script to the docker-entrpoint.sh file or init folder, I do get the wal archive restore to work correctly (on my Ubuntu PC).

On the armv71 architecture however on my Raspberry Pi, this exact same code results in the following error in the container logs:

```
initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
db_1                           | If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
db_1                           | the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" or run initdb
db_1                           | with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql/data".
```

It is saying that the directory is not empty, but it should be as I just deleted it with the previous line, and the code works fine on Ubuntu.  Also on the Pi, I have watched from within the container to confirm that the directory does go empty as it should before restart.  What is going on?

Another interesting fact, this process above works fine on both architectures using `postgres 11`, I am only having difficulty since updating to `postgres 12`.

Any idea why PG 12 is causing this issue with armv71?  This is easily reproducible if you have a pi.

In case its important, the following are the postgresql versions I am using:

```
PostgreSQL 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1) on arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6)
PostgreSQL 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence you describe tries to delete the PostgreSQL data directory *while the database is still running*.  This is likely to just confuse things; when `docker stop` signals the database to shut down it will probably write some data out into that directory, so when it restarts, it won't actually be empty.

Typical use of these database containers is to use the `docker run -v` option to mount some storage into the container, so that if you delete and recreate the container, there's still persistent state.

```sh
docker run \
  --name website_db_1 \
  --net website_net -p 5432:5432 \
  -v $PWD/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  postgres:12
```

So when these instructions say to delete the database state, they mean to stop the container, and delete the host storage:

```sh
docker stop website_db_1
docker rm website_db_1
rm -rf postgres
mkdir postgres
docker run \
  --name website_db_1 \
  --net website_net -p 5432:5432 \
  -v $PWD/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  postgres:12
```

(In routine use you shouldn't need to use `docker exec` to administer or operate containers.  The `postgres` image behavior here of doing all required initialization automatically on first startup is pretty typical.  If you need to run the `psql` shell you can do it from the host or another container.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I agree your approach is the much more sensible/stable/correct! way of doing it.  I have permission issues however with the ownership of the data directory which prevent me from using a mounted volume on the data directory.  I receive the error `FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership`, when I use -v to create the volume.

Comment: I am sure there is a reason for this, but using a named volume 'solves' the permissions problem.  I am able therefore to create an ancilliary container which is able to modify the db container's content, including deleting the data directory and indeed operating on the config files to enable wal archiving, restores etc.  I'm surprised this is the correct approach with docker, but it certainly appears to fit the pattern.  Feel free to update your answer if you wish with a named volume instead of one with a locally defined path.  Thanks very much

Comment: if you add a volume to docker via -v option you have to ensure if the container user (i assume it is not root as in default it is postgres -> https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/33bccfcaddd0679f55ee1028c012d26cd196537d/12/Dockerfile#L18) has the ownership of the directory. in this case the uid should match to uid 999 on dockerhost as well.